# Trying to connect to a port via SSH to test Java Program

Tags: java, ssh, server, port, serversocket

I am attempting to follow a tutorial in a book to make a simple program that utilizes the `ServerSocket` object. The program just attempts to print a simple message to the client and be able to echo anything the client types in. I know the port I am using is open since I checked the activity of the port using `lsof -i:8189` which returns the fact that I have a program listening on the port. I also now the port must connect to the program since the moment I close my terminal my program does what it is supposed to do. It closes the socket and terminates.

The problem here is when I test my program using ssh nothing comes up the port is just active but what is supposed to be outputted is not. My code is here:

```
public class tutorial {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {





    try(ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(8189)) {

        try(Socket incoming = s.accept()) {

            InputStream inStream = incoming.getInputStream();
            OutputStream outStream = incoming.getOutputStream();

            try(Scanner in = new Scanner(inStream, "UTF-8")) {

                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outStream, "UTF-8"), true);

                out.println("Hey dude");

                boolean done = false;

                while(!done && in.hasNextLine()) {
                    String line = in.nextLine();
                    out.println("The line you typed is: " + line);
                    if(line.trim().equals("BYE")) {
                        done = true;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

}

}
```

When running this I do not get any exceptions or problems. I test it with a command in this form: `ssh -p 8189 username@localhost`. After this nothing happens as should but the port and socket are connected. What have I done wrong? Is the code wrong to begin with? Or am I testing it wrong? A quick note is that the book I have uses telnet for this but a mac only comes preinstalled with ssh so I am trying to do it with ssh for now.

Comment: use telnet not ssh

Comment: @ScaryWombat ok but lets say for now I want to use ssh is it technically possible or do I absolutely need telnet?

Comment: ssh is a different protocol that uses authentication see https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/Secure-Shell

Comment: @ScaryWombat thanks for the info. In the meantime I also found out that macs have netcat preinstalled which essentially does the same job as telnet and my program worked.

Comment: *and my program worked.* GREAT